# unnecessary uitableview delegate methods

Tags: uitableview, delegates

I inherited another developer code, but didn't understood the following code:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.0;
}

-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return nil;
}

-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return nil;
}
```

Is anything can happen if i'll delete it ?
it seems unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need them just comment them out. You 'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Those methods are just part of the UITablieView "appearance" of the table. It is the string that is displayed under a section in your TableView. You can just comment them out or delete them totally, this won't affect your program.